# How to disable python warnings that only show up after converting the .py to a .exe?

Tags: python, parsing, warnings, pyinstaller

[screenshot of the warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ierHp.png)

I just started programing on python, I'm programing a parser and I'm having trouble trying to hide the warnings, such as:

WARNING: There are 2 unused tokens

Generating LALR tables

WARNING: 87 shift/reduce conflicts

WARNING: 2 reduce/reduce conflicts

The program works, but when I convert the .py to .exe, the warning show up on the .exe but not on the .py.
I'm using the library PLY, I read that this yacc.yacc(errorlog=yacc.NullLogger()) would silence the warnings but it did not work, I believe that maybe the problem comes up when converting the file(I used pyinstaller)
I would appreciate any piece of advice you can give me, thanks.

Comment: I added a link with a screenshot of the warnings that show up on the .exe

Answer (score 0):

Use the catch_warnings() function, which allows you to catch warnings you know will appear. See below for an example from this website: https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html

```
import warnings

def fxn():
    warnings.warn("deprecated", DeprecationWarning)

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    fxn()
```

Here, the writer wants to use a deprecated function but uses catch_warnings() to prevent the warning. Hope this helps!

Comment: How do I know wich type of warning I have?

Comment: Can you post the specific warnings that you received? Like the traceback when you run the program.